# How to hide main menu if all menu items are hidden in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, menu

I have main menu Called Entries. and it has many submenu items.
base on setting submenu can be set visible = false.

I want to hide Entries Main menu if all its submenus are hidden.

Here I try

```
int Count = 0;
foreach (ToolStripDropDownItem mnu in entriesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems)
{
    if (mnu.Visible)
    {
        Count++;
    }
}
if (Count == 0)
{
    entriesToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
}
```

but problem is that `if (mnu.Visible)` always returns false because submenu visible property is false due to Entries main menu not expanded. when I click on Entries then sub menus item's visible property is coming = true.

I want to hide it in form load event.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Tag property

```
int Count = 0;
foreach (ToolStripDropDownItem mnu in entriesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems)
{
    if (mnu.Tag==1)
    {
        Count++;
    }
}
if (Count == 0)
{
    entriesToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
}
```